# JavaFX table row color, too many database connections

Tags: mysql, javafx, tableview

I want to to print my row red when book is out of stock but i am getting error like that every time i try new idea to manage that:

> "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from
>   server: "Too many connections"

Even if i try to close all connections in same loop...
So here we go:

```
private boolean checkIfOutOfStock(BookDetail book) throws SQLException{
    String query = "select * from tbl_loan where book_id = " + book.getId() + " ";

    dc = new DbConnection();
    conn = dc.connect();

    PreparedStatement checkPst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet checkRs = checkPst.executeQuery(query);

    if(checkRs.next()){
        checkRs.close();
        checkPst.close();
        return true;
    } else 
        {
            checkRs.close();
            checkPst.close();
            return false;
        }
}

@Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        dc = new DbConnection();
        conn = dc.connect();


        selectionModel = editTabPane.getSelectionModel();


        editTableBooks.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<BookDetail>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(BookDetail item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty) ;
                if (item == null) {
                    setStyle("");
                } else
                    try {
                        if (checkIfOutOfStock(item)) {
                            setStyle("-fx-background-color: tomato;");
                        } else {
                            setStyle("");
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        });
    }
```

It works fine until i slide up and down table few times... its like everytime i slide table im opening new connection. Any idea how to solve it?

Hey do you mean something like that?

```
editTableBooks.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<BookDetail>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(BookDetail item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty) ;
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {


                    if (item == null) {
                        setStyle("");
                    } else
                        try {
                            if (checkIfOutOfStock(item)) {
                                setStyle("-fx-background-color: tomato;");
                            } else {
                                setStyle("");
                            }
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                }
            });

        }
    });
```

It doesn't change anything or i just didn't get it :P

Comment: Every time you scroll you will likely be creating many new database connections. Is it not possible to get this information when you first load the `BookDetail` objects from the database? Also note that your `Platform.runLater(...)` is completely redundant here: the `updateItem(..)` method is already being executed on the FX Application Thread.

Comment: Book storage is changing in other table, so when i select that table which i want to be colored - I arleady know which book in that table will be colored thx to my checkIfOutOfStock() function so yes, one initialization should be enough (+ on button refresh ) but how to do this in that way? :P I have no idea honestly, barely made that code... ; /

Comment: "Other table" in your GUI, or other table in the database? If it's in the GUI then you will be updating the (local) `BookDetail` object anyway, so there would be no need to communicate with the database. So your table row factory can just check the field in the `BookDetail` object

Comment: Not really. I have tbl_book and tbl_loan in database. Now, TableView - which we are talking about - holds data from tbl_books (BookDetail model of tbl_book). If any of those books(BookDetail.id) is already also in tbl_loan -> it means it is borrowed so i want it to be red painted

Comment: I did it on local BookDetail list like you said and it works just as i expect :)